# SceneKit 'clip to bounds' equivalent

Tags: ios, scenekit

Other than camera xFov, yFov, zNear and zFar, is there a way with SceneKit to have a node (and its descendants) 'clip to bounds', i.e. to specify an arbitrary 3D bounding box whereby any nodes that fall outside it would not be rendered?

My use case is as follows:

I have a SceneView with a clear color background that is displayed on top of a separate map view.

I only want to display nodes in my 3D model that are notionally 'above' the ground (i.e. above the map). When the map is flat, I can do that very easily by setting zFar on the SceneKit camera and positioning the camera directly on the positive Z-axis.

However, if the map is tilted, then I need to adjust my Scene camera to match the map tilt. However, at that point, the camera z-axis is no longer orthogonal to the scene content and zFar would 'reveal' nodes in the model that are notionally below the map.

(This would be easy if the map content were part of the SceneKit node hierarchy - just define a floor and render the map on the floor. But the map is displayed in a separate view that sits below the SceneKit view.)

Hence, I'm looking to define a plane or bounding box outside which SceneKit nodes are not rendered, but which can be controlled independently of the camera frustum.

(At least that's what I think I need - perhaps there's another way...)

**Update**

I found I can implement renderer(aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) for the SCNView delegate, and  iterate through my scene nodes and test for world position, hiding or showing as desired. However that feels a bit expensive and inefficient - I'm wondering if there's a better approach?

Comment: Another approach would be to "fill" the depth buffer with a plane that matches your tilted map. That way you could rely on the depth test to cull your 3d objects per fragment. That said, to fill the depth buffer without rendering to the color buffer, you will probably have to cheat (like rendering a plane with opacity close to 0 but not 0 - otherwise the fragment will be discarded before writing to the depth buffer). A shader modifier or custom shader might help

Comment: Yes - that seems to work. I hadn't realised that was even possible - it seems rather a limitation for using the opacity property (i.e. something that is not opaque will mask out other objects that lie behind it), but it definitely provides a solution for my problem!

PS. If you want to write it up as an answer I can accept it.